# Opening URL from OpenERP using import webbrowser

Tags: python, odoo

I am trying to open a test url, from python code, in OpenERP, in a new tab. Nothing happens in my browser (Firefox) but in the terminal window it looks like the page is opened in text mode. I want to open an url in the browser's new tab.
What am I doing wrong?

Here is the code:

```
class mrp_bom_line(osv.osv):
    _inherit = 'mrp.bom.line'

    def action_go(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
                webbrowser.open_new_tab('http://www.python.org')
                <.... other code...>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right now you you are attempting to open a browser on the **server**, using the `webbrowser` python module. I'll assume that your real intention was to show the page to the **user**, i.e. open in on the client side (on user's computer).

To achieve that you need to use Odoo's [URL Action](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/actions.html#url-actions-ir-actions-act-url):

```
class mrp_bom_line(osv.osv):
    _inherit = 'mrp.bom.line'

    def action_go(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
        return {
            'type': 'ir.actions.act_url',
            'url': 'http://www.python.org',
            'target': 'new',
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, Ludwik. I already have the code you have mentioned as a solution. The reason I tried to use webbrowser is that I hope it opens the page in a new tab. If I use your code, Firefox blocks the popup window. I know that I can change the settings for popups in Firefox, but I don't want that. I want to launch new tab directly from OpenERP bypassing browsers block popup message. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know of a way.